# Литература C# + UML + многомерные базы данных + WPF

Tags: c#, база-данных, книги

Прошу посоветовать литературу (или бесплатные курсы) для самостоятельного овладения необходимыми знаниями. Цель - научиться:

1. проектировать БД, используя CASE-средство;
2. создавать реляционные и многомерные БД;
3. разрабатывать пользовательские интерфейсы для работы с БД.

Знания минимальны. Изучил некоторые основы C#, поверхностно основы БД.
Нужна рекомендация на книгу (курс) или перечень книг "по порядку" для эффективного обучения. Проблема больше в завязке: многомерная БД и С#

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c

Comment: @Zicrael наверно, но и литературу можно списком

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Comment: Там ссылку выше скинули, по С#.

Comment: @Shpunder благодарю, но хотелось бы конкретную рекомендацию, пошаговую.

Comment: @Zicrael я не просто ссылку скинул, я отметил вопрос как дубликат

Comment: @tym32167 нет. проблема на самом деле больше в разработке многомерной бд и работе с ней

Comment: @in_trance пошаговых инструкций что изучать нет. Хотите работать на C# - учите C#, хотите работать с БД - смотрите материалы про БД. Хотите интерфейсов - это отдельная наука с отдельными книгами/руководствами и прочим. Никто кроме вас не знает, что вам надо читать

Comment: @tym32167 Зачем читать все книги? Когда нужно 3-4 для достижения целей. Список книг по C# точно не решает проблему. Один подскажет по UML, другой - по многомерным, третий - по работе с бд из c#. Так ведь сообщество и помогает?

Comment: Уже 3 дня тыркаюсь по нету - ничего толкового по многомерным бд нет, литература 5 - 10 летней давности.

Comment: а все книги и не надо. Читайте только те, что по вашей теме. Хотите десктоп и WPF - это одна книга, хотите MongoDB - это другая. Выбирайте только те книги, что именно вам полезны

Comment: я не знаю, что вы имеете ввиду под многомерными БД, но если вы про OLAP, то по моему оно есть как в книгах по SQL Server, так и под Oracle, может и ещё под какие то БД

Comment: @tym32167 да, про OLAP речь. С БД тз-за отсутствия опыта теряюсь - с чего начать? Их целая тьма. Пытался с SQLite начать. Оказалось - многомерную БД с ней не построить.

Comment: раз изучаете c# и нет опыта с БД, то начните с MS SQL + entity framework. Так же много информация для начала есть на сайте metanit.com

Comment: Очевидно, вам надо сначала определиться, что конкретно вам надо от БД, потом найти все БД, что поддерживают то, что вам надо, выбрать из них одну и её изучать. Конкретных ответов вам никто не даст, так как они зависят от того, что вам надо сделать.

Comment: @Shpunder а какую книгу по MS SQL посоветуешь?  "Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Основы T-SQL" пойдет?

Comment: по MS SQL лучше не с книги начинать, а начните делать какое-либо приложение с использованием БД и по ходу решайте возникающие вопросы. Разберетесь в принципе работы БД, а потом если необходимо будет уже углубите знания.